# How to do a simple import of a style in Preact as you would do in React?

Tags: sass, preact

In React, in order to style a component, I simply import the style file that sits in the same directory as the component, e.g., `import './style.scss'`. It's simple and easy, no problems there.

However, I can't seem to make this work in Preact. The style file just never get applied, even after following the docs and of course installing `node-sass` and `sass-loader`. I see plenty of examples out there using CSS modules and a few with CSS in JS, but I'd like to do a bog-standard import if possible.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently the solution was to disable CSS modules altogether by installing `css-loader` and adding the following to my preact.config.js:

```
const css = helpers.getLoadersByName(config, 'css-loader')[0];
css.loader.options.modules = false;
```